# Нейросеть. Как правильно указывать метки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Сложилась такая ситуация, что чем дольше я разбираюсь с нейросетью, тем меньше я понимаю что происходит...
Поэтому я решил начать с самого начала. У меня есть несколько вопросов, но начну я с самого первого.

У меня есть набор данных. Каждую строку данных я отношу к одной из 3-х категорий (0-1-2).

Вопрос, как правильно добавить метки для обучения сети:

```
это должен быть один выходной нейрон: [или 0, или 1, или 2]

это должно быть три нейрона: или [1,0,0], или [0,1,0], или [0,0,1]

или как-то по другому
```

Данные состоят из числовых значений, которые я нормализую, привожу в диапозон от 0 до 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C), которая хоть и не самый полезный источник, но все-таки весьма достоверный для не специалиста: "Топология такой сети характеризуется тем, что количество нейронов в выходном слое, как правило, равно количеству определяемых классов."

Разумеется, существуют исключения, как например, бинарная классификация, в которой обычно используется один нейрон на выходном слое, или классификация на категории вида "мало"-"нормально"-"много", где категории связаны между собой каким-то конкретным возрастающим признаком (который может быть и не обозначен во входных данных), но второй случай ближе к регрессии.

Также стоит отметить, что в случае использования трех (или любого другого количества) нейронов в зависимости от активационной функции нейронного слоя вы можете получать не только выходные вектора [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], но и, к примеру, [0.7, 0.2, 0.1], где эти числа обычно обозначают вероятность того, что входной объект относится к конкретной категории.

Обозначение же лейбла зависит от метода потерь. Для задач классификации наиболее часто используется CategoricalCrossentropy и его собрат SparseCategoricalCrossentropy. Для использование первого метода вам нужно применить One-Hot кодирование меток (все численные метки переводятся в бинарные вектора, например 2 -> [0, 0, 1], 1 -> [0, 1, 0]). А для использования второго вы можете (и должны) использовать обычные числа в качестве классов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А можете мне ещё немного помочь?
Дело в том, что строка в моём csv-файле выглядит так:
0.1428571428571428,0.4583333333333333,....,0.00538,0.006524,1.0,0.0,0.0
Последние 3 значения - это я так записываю к какой категории относится эта запись. При подготовке сети к обучению, я определяю эти три значения как метки. И делаю сеть с выходным слоем в три нейрона. Это правильно? Или выходной слой должен иметь только один нейрон?

Comment: @VipAvoS выходной слой для классификации должен иметь почти всегда количество нейронов, равное количеству классов. У вас он должен состоять из трех нейронов.

Comment: Спасибо. Ну и ещё одно уточнение - Если сеть у меня с тремя выходными нейронами, то по идее нужно использовать SparseCategoricalCrossentropy. Верно? Но при запуске обучения оно на меня матерится ;) А вот при запуске с CategoricalCrossentropy обучение идёт нормально. Получается что сеть воспринимает мои последние 3 значения как бинарный вектор? Или она воспринимает каждое из этих значений как вектор? Это связано с тем, что они в формате float? Нужно ли перед подачей в сеть объявлять их как int ?

Comment: @VipAvoS сама задача классификации предполагает три нейрона, но функция потерь выбирается не в зависимости от количества нейронов, а от личных предпочтений и вида подготовленных данных. Если у вас в Y_train находится вектор из чисел вида [0, 2, 1, 1 ... 2, 0], то нужно использовать sparse, а если у вас вектор векторов вида [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0] ... [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]], то обычную кроссэнтропию. Это просто издержки реализации каждого из методов.

Comment: @VipAvoS приложите, пожалуйста к вопросу, свои матрицы X_data и y_data (ну или опишите их вид), если вопросы еще остались.

Comment: Остались. И я очень хочу разобраться. Как тут приложить файлы я не знаю. Залил в формате .npz на файлообменник. Ссылка для скачивания: https://transfiles.ru/8pglq . Так выглядят по принту X_train: 
[[4.28571429e-01 7.08333333e-01 1.38360000e-01 ... 8.33333333e-01
  2.69000000e-04 1.14000000e-03]
 ...
 [7.14285714e-01 5.00000000e-01 1.29358000e-01 ... 5.41666667e-01
  5.24000000e-04 5.80000000e-04]]
........ А так y_train: 
[[0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 ...
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]]